# Query to get latest training date

Tags: mysql

We have 2 tables one is driver with all the driver details and the table is dTraining.

Structure for driver is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `driver` (
  `driverID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `clientID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `driverName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `driverDateOfBirth` date NOT NULL,  
  `driverStatus` enum('a','d','i') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Structure for dTraining is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dTraining` (
  `dTrainingID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `cTrainingID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `trainingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `driverID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `clientID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `driverTrainingDate` date NOT NULL,
  `driverTrainingUpdateStatus` enum('d','a') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I need is that when I run a query like this should give be the latest training from the many training data which the driver has. So I need help on how to run the subquery there.

```
SELECT driver.driverID,dTraining.driverTrainingDate
 FROM   driver,dTraining
```

Currently I have this query . Sample output will be

```
driverID=1 , driverTrainingDate=2013-02-01
driverID=2 , driverTrainingDate=2013-02-02

SELECT driver.driverID,b.driverTrainingDate
 FROM   driver
             LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT B1.*
                      FROM   dTraining AS B1
                             LEFT JOIN  dTraining AS B2
                                    ON B1.driverID = B2.driverID
                                       AND B1.cTrainingID = B2.cTrainingID 
                                       AND B1.driverTrainingDate< B2.driverTrainingDate
                      WHERE B1.cTrainingID =".$cTID." And B2.driverID IS NULL) as b
ON ( driver.driverID= b.driverID)
```

What I am curious why do we need to put B1.driverTrainingDate< B2.driverTrainingDate and not B1.driverTrainingDate> B2.driverTrainingDate and the need for B2.driverID IS NULL

Comment: Explore the `MAX()` MySQL function, and for standards sake please don't use implicit joins.

Comment: @Crontab I have update is there now in the dTraining table. What do you discourage implicit joins?

Comment: Implicit joins have been deprecated for years and they're harder to read.  When you explicitly join tables, you give any other developer reading your code a clearer picture of exactly what you intend the query to do.

Comment: @Crontab how do you difference between implicit and explicit joins?

Comment: An implicit join is the `FROM driver, dTraining` thing you're doing.  An explicit join would be `FROM driver d LEFT OUTER JOIN dTraining dt ON dt.field = d.field`.  More verbose, yes, but also more descriptive.

Comment: @Crontab sorry kind of confuse isn't this explicit join FROM   driver
LEFT JOIN (

Comment: Yes, that is.  From what I remember, that wasn't in your post when I left that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left join with B2 returns trainings that happened after these of B1, that's why if none exist (`B2.driverID is null`) you're sure B1's training is the last one.

Comment: I dont get you when you sure of B1's training is the last one. My problem is that I want to get the latest training based on driverTrainingDate. So to optimise the query?

Comment: the filter of the left join says explicitely `B1.driverTrainingDate < B2.driverTrainingDate` so if a row is returned in the recordset of B2, it means B1 is not the last one. Therefore, the logical opposite of this assertion is saying "so, if there's no record in B2, it means my B1's record is the last one."

Comment: if B2 is indeed bigger then B1 then why do we need to pick SELECT B1.* and why not SELECT B2.*

Comment: because which one of b2? don't forget we need the BIGGEST. The only way on ensuring it is to be sure there's nothing bigger.

Comment: is just like for a loop can I say ?

Comment: exactly!! that what basically is happening when joins are made: the resultset of the first table is crossed with the resultset of the 2nd one in a for loop, filtering in/out according to the ON clause.

Answer (score 1):

try this, change `'123'` for the driverID:

```
select d.*,t.* 
from driver as d
inner join dtraining as t
on d.driverId=t.driverId
where d.driverid in (1,2,3,4.......10000)
order by t.driverTrainingDate desc
limit 1
```

Comment: this will just give me one driver I want all the drivers how will that work then?